# GoogleMaps setMyLocationEnabled(true) not updating (Genymotion)

Tags: android, google-maps, genymotion, android-permissions, genymotion-gps

I'm updating my code with permissions from the new `Android API 23`. If I want to show user's location I just have to `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`. If I have the permission I can see user's location, if I don't have permission I don't make this API call but after requesting the permissions and user accepts giving Location permissions I can't update the map with user's location. I've tried 2 approaches:

**Approach 1 (rebuild map):**

```
 private void populateMap() {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                    ...
                    if (PermissionsManager.getInstance().hasLocationPermissions(getActivity())) {
                        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        request permissions...
                    }
                    ...
                }
        }
 }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PermissionsManager.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    populateMap();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Approach 2 (use map instance and update it):**

```
private void populateMap() {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                    mMap = map;
                    ...
                    if (PermissionsManager.getInstance().hasLocationPermissions(getActivity())) {
                        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        request permissions...
                    }
                    ...
               }
        }
}

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PermissionsManager.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
                if (mMap!= null && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

In both approaches the location button is shown, but the blue dot with user's location doesn't. 
What am I missing here? Thanks.

ps: Of course If I kill my Fragment and launch it again everything works fine, this issue happens when I have to prompt user for permissions and then update the map with my location after user's authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was testing with `Genymotion` because I couldn't get my hands on a device with `Android` 6.0 but now, that I've borrowed one, I've tested this code in that physical device and I was happy to notice that it works.
Guess it's a `Genymotion` problem. Oh well, code's working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

could you please use the following code and feed me back with result :-

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Sets the map type to be "hybrid"
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startActivity(getIntent());
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input but see my "ps". If I kill the fragment and restart it again it works, but I want to avoid that, and that's what your code does, finishing and restarting. I want to update the map without killing my Fragment. Thanks.